# Is there a way to get a user's account ID given his site's user ID?

Tags: support, users, scripts

I'm trying to modify [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/9039/80115) of mine to make it work on all sites but I couldn't find a way to get the account ID (i.e., network profile ID) for a user.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2.3 SE API has a `account_id` property on the [`shallow_user`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user) object, which is the user's SE account ID, so you can get the user's SE account number from any request which returns that object as part of the response (e.g. any question, answer, post, etc.). Adding that property was one of the changes in the 2.3 SE API and allows you to obtain the user's account ID from many endpoints as part of getting other data. Getting the `account_id` from such endpoints can be a significant savings in request quota, depending on what you're doing.

If you are wanting to make a request specifically to get the `account_id`, you can get that property in the [`user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) returned by the [`/users/{ids}` endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids). That `account_id` property is the user's SE account ID.

Once you have the `account_id`, you could use the [`/users/{ids}/associated` endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) to get the IDs for all of the profiles associated with that SE account on different sites.